# Theorem 2.14 in Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've got some difficult for understanding Theorem 2.14 in baby rudin.

> **Theorem 2.14.** Let $A$ be the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits 0 and 1. This set $A$ is uncountable.
>
> The elements of $A$ are sequences like 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...

Rudin gave a proof looks correct.

But with **Theorem 2.12**, I figure out a proof that gets a opposite conclusion.

> **Theorem 2.12.** Let $\{E_n\}, n=1, 2, 3,...,$ be a sequence of countable sets, and put $S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Then S is countable.
>
> **Collary.** Suppose $A$ is at most countable, and, for every $\alpha\in{A}$, $B_\alpha$ is at most countable. Put $T=\bigcup_{\alpha\in{A}}B_\alpha$. Then $T$ is at most countable.

And my proof for the set $A$ in **Theorem 2.14** is countable:

> **My proof**:
> Let $A_n$ be the set of length $n$'s sequences whose elements are digits 0 and 1. $A_n$ is at most countable. So, with **Theorem 2.12**, $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$ is at most countable. That means the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits 0 and 1 is countable.

I know I definitely made a mistake, but where is it?

Comment: You mistake is that you are only counting sequences which are eventually zero.

Comment: could you explain more? @uniquesolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$ are only sequences of finite length ! For example the sequence $(1,1,1,....)$ is not in $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$

Comment: I think the notation $\infty$ means infinite length...

Comment: No. It means the union of all sequences of finite length

Comment: In Definition 2.9 in baby rudin, it says "The symbol $\infty$ merely indicates that the union of a  countable col­lection of sets is taken", why not infinite length?

Comment: To say the sequence $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is in the union, is to say that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $(1, 1, 1, \ldots) \in A_n$. It therefore means that $(1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ is of (finite) length $n$. This is absurd! Therefore it cannot belong to any $A_n$, so it's not in the union.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

The union of all $A_n$'s is the set of all *finite* seqeunces of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Comment: The notation $\infty$ means all the integers, doesn't it?

Comment: @JohnnyJi The notation $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ means $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\ldots$ Does this answer your question?

Comment: $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$ means $A_1\bigcup{A_2}\bigcup{A_3}\bigcup...\bigcup{A_\infty}$, is this right?

Comment: @JohnnyJi No, you're wrong. It means what I wrote: $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\ldots$ Besides, what is $A_\infty$? Where did you define it? What makes you think that it is countable?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I've checked the definition of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{A_n}$, you're right, there is no $A_\infty$, it only means that the union of a countable collections of sets. But still, I don't understand why the set of all positive integers doesn't include the infinite posivite number.

Comment: @JohnnyJi Even if it did, that would no change the fact that you did not define $A_\infty$.

Comment: Still don't understand. So does the union of all $A_n$ include the infinite sequences of 0s and 1s or not? "the set of all sequences whose elements are the digits 0 and 1" include the infinite sequences? Sorry to bother you...

Comment: @JohnnyJi **No**. The union of all $A_n$ includes *no* infinite sequence, only finite ones.

Comment: Got it. I think Fred's comment is more easy to understand. You also think his comment is right?

Comment: @JohnnyJi No. I *know* he is right.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting only sequences of finite length.  Rudin considers sequences of infinite length.

**added**

Your set $A_7$ consists of sequences of length $7$.  Rudin's set $A$ had no sequences of length $7$.  So your union is not a subset of $A$.

Does your union involve a set $A_\infty$, sequences of infinite length?  if so, then you are wrong when you say $A_n$ is at most countable, since you have not proved that $A_\infty$ is at most countable.